# Django Switcher behaving unexpectedly

Tags: python, django

I have a switcher object that as I understand it would return the value function if it has matched the key in the parameters. Here is the code to better understand the process:

```
import logging
# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test_switch(request):

    first_switcher = {
        'first': first_call(),
        'second': second_call(),
        'third': third_call(),
        'fourth': fourth_call()
    }

    second_switcher = {
        'one': one_fxn(),
        'two': two_fxn(),
        'three': three_fxn()
    }

    if first_switcher.get('first', False):
        if second_switcher.get('one', False):
            logger.info("got here")

def first_call():
    logger.info('first switcher first args') 
    return True

def second_call():
    logger.info('first switcher second args') 
    return True

def third_call():
    logger.info('first switcher third args') 
    return True

def fourth_call():
    logger.info('first switcher fourth args') 
    return True

def one_fxn():
    logger.info('second switcher one args') 
    return True
    
def two_fxn():
    logger.info('second switcher two args') 
    return True

def three_fxn():
    logger.info('second switcher three args') 
    return True
```

The program is expected to return the value function it matched the key into. Something like this:

```
first switcher first args
second switcher one args
got here
```

But it's calling all the functions as seen in the log files.

```
first switcher first args
first switcher second args
first switcher third args
first switcher fourth args
second switcher one args
second switcher two args
second switcher three args
got here
```

May I ask what I'm missing? And if you could recommend any alternative to the whole switch process in django, it would be appreciated.

Comment: You call all the functions when you create the dictionary there (eg. `'first': first_call(),` you are **calling** the function here), so all of those are logged.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat. yeah, thank you. I should've known it was being called. Anyway the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it for me:

```
#partials is used to specify the arguments when the dictionary is created
from functools import partial
import logging
# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test_switch(request):

    first_switcher = {
        'first': first_call,
        'second': second_call,
        'third': third_call,
        'fourth': fourth_call
    }

    second_switcher = {
        'one': one_fxn,
        'two': two_fxn,
        'three': three_fxn
    }

    if first_switcher['first']():
        if second_switcher.get['one']():
            logger.info("got here")

def first_call():
    logger.info('first switcher first args') 
    return True

def second_call():
    logger.info('first switcher second args') 
    return True

def third_call():
    logger.info('first switcher third args') 
    return True

def fourth_call():
    logger.info('first switcher fourth args') 
    return True

def one_fxn():
    logger.info('second switcher one args') 
    return True
    
def two_fxn():
    logger.info('second switcher two args') 
    return True

def three_fxn():
    logger.info('second switcher three args') 
    return True
```